# Property transfer to request header

Tags: testing, soap, soapui

How can I transfer a property from a response to a header in another request not the body?

Can it be done using property transfer, and how?

Comment: I figured it out , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send some headers with :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap

def headers = new StringToStringMap()
headers.put("SOAPAction","some value")

//retrieve your teststep to a variable
def teststep = [...]
// then:
teststep.testRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers)
```

The value you set to the header can be a variable retrieved from another step before.